# Where to find the article(s) saying that 3D Navier-Stokes solutions exist in case of a small initial velocity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, velocity, flow, navier-stokes

I've already been searching for here and on the internet, maybe not enough.

PS: this result is stated in the Clay Mathematics Institute N-S problem definition, page 2: https://www.claymath.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/navierstokes.pdf